# Can't access bitstreams in assetstore after upgrading from DSpace 3.2 to 5.2

Tags: dspace

I've just upgraded from DSpace 3.2 to 5.2. Everything looks fine except that I can't open bitstreams.
Whenever I click on an item's file, a new blank tab is opened and it eventually displays a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Facts:

- The database information looks fine, as I checked the table's chain `handle->bundle->bitstream` and `bitstream.internal_id` translates to a valid filesystem path to the bitstream file.
- In `dspace.cfg`, `assetstore.dir` points to `[dspace32]/assetstore`, the assetstore from the (old) DSpace 3.2.
- It doesn't seem to be a network issue since I get the same outcome when accessing the bitstream locally using wget. (eg.: `wget -vd --no-proxy http://localhost:8180/jspui/bitstream/123456789/156/3/000156.pdf`)
- The only piece of log that seems to be associated with this issue is this one:

  `2015-07-22 13:40:47,865 INFO org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.BitstreamServlet @ anonymous:session_id=8F3B259C29333982128AB583EE4FC894:ip_addr=127.0.0.1:view_bitstream:bitstream_id=2858`

The above `bitstream_id` is correct, by the way.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! ;)

Here is my system information:

- OpenSuse 11.2
- Apache Ant 1.9.6
- Apache Maven 3.3.3
- Apache Tomcat 8.0.24
- DSpace 5.2
- Oracle Java JDK 1.7u80
- PostgreSQL 9.4.4

***UPDATE***: I also can't access a newly uploaded file, so it might no be an upgrade issue at all. In this case, DSpace correctly creates the new bitstream in filesystem and database, but I can't access it using the UI.

Comment: Did you run `psql -U dspace -f [dspace]/etc/postgres/update-sequences.sql`? Source: [Upgrade Steps (Step 10b)](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Upgrading+DSpace#UpgradingDSpace-UpgradeSteps)

Comment: Another potential culprit could be difference in user between user running tomcat, and user owning the files in your dspace directory. Can you verify which user you are starting tomcat with & compare this to the user that owns the files, and notably, the assetstore directory?

Comment: @BramLuyten Same user, right permissions

Comment: From your system info, I'm seeing you're using Tomcat 8. Can you also reproduce the problem on tomcat 7? Reason I'm asking is that there is no official support for Tomcat 8 yet, and one known thing that may cause issues with Tomcat 8: https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-2437

Comment: @BramLuyten Well, we chose Tomcat8 because the documentation reads, in the `Prerequisite Software` section, that it supports `Apache Tomcat 7 or later`: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-ServletEngine%28ApacheTomcat7orlater,Jetty,CauchoResinorequivalent%29

Answer (score 0):

Commenting the following section of `[dspace]/webapps/jspui/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml` did the trick:

```
<!-- Google Analytics recording  -->
<bean class="org.dspace.google.GoogleRecorderEventListener">
    <property name="eventService" >
        <ref bean="dspace.eventService"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, why in hell a failure to access Google Analytics, that we didn't activate and shouldn't exist in the first place, should prevent the download of a file? Here's the dspace.log:

```
2015-07-24 11:46:33,744 INFO  org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.BitstreamServlet @ anonymous:session_id=8928432521F497D8ADFBA09FD3C65C90:ip_addr=SERVER_IP:view_bitstream:bitstream_id=2858
2015-07-24 11:50:30,940 INFO  org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec @ I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://www.google-analytics.com:443: The network is out of reach
2015-07-24 11:50:30,941 INFO  org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec @ Retrying request to {s}->https://www.google-analytics.com:443
```

**CAVEAT**: we have a proxy in the network but just setting `http.proxy` won't work because DSpace will only pass HTTP requests through it.